# What does this.object.method(this) do?

Tags: java, this

For example object1 has an instance method1:

```
public void method1() {
    this.object2.method2(this);
}
```

Would the first 'this' refer to the object 1 and the second 'this' object 2 ?

Comment: No, `this` in this case both means `object1`, from this code you can tell the there is a field in this class that is called `object2`

Comment: write a test program and find out :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code the `this` keyword give the method a sense of which variable, object or instance it will call, while `this` can also call the parents variable, object, instance or method. So when it calls `this.object2.method2(this)` it actually calling for the `object2`'s `method2` with a parameter of the class.
In your scope there is a code that instantiate the `object2` and it is declared outside any method of the class. See more in here: [use of this (javadocs)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)